# No Bluetooth on Intel 7265 WLAN card (Dell XPS 13)

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, 15.04, intel, xps

I recently purchase a Dell XPS 13 (9343), installed Ubuntu 15.04 and replace the Broadcom 4352 card with an Intel 7265 card due to Broadcom's horrible support for Linux and crappy signal. Wi-Fi works great now however bluetooth isn't enable (under settings it's grayed out).
It's enable on the BIOS and BIOS has been updated to latest version. Can't check if it works on Windows since I completely erase it.

```
rfkill list all; hciconfig -a
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include results from `rfkill list all; hciconfig -a`

Comment: Are you sure there is bluetooth in this card? It is not always the case.

Comment: @Jeremy31 edit done

Comment: @Pilot6 [Yes, card does support bluetooth](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-7265.html)

Comment: You can write it as an answer. It may help someone.

Comment: Do not edit the question. Write it as an answer please.

Comment: @Pilot6 Wouldn't that just clutter up the thread?

Comment: This is not a forum and this is not a thread. You asked a question. So answer it and accept tomorrow. This is how it is done here.

Comment: Some do not have bluetooth.  Intel will have the wifi MAC and bluetooth MAC addresses on the sticker on the card labelled WFM for the wifi MAC and BDM for the bluetooth MAC, if the sticker doesn't have BDM listed on it, it doesn't have bluetooth.  [This](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-N-7265-7265NGW-NB-NGFF-Card-/191413863320?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c9127c398) doesn't have bluetooth, [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Intel-Dual-Band-Wireless-AC-7265-7265NGW-NGFF-Card-802-11ac-867m-2x2-Wifi-BT4-0-/201243347654?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2edb09cac6) one does

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks, turns out the WLAN card I have doesn't have bluetooth. Wasn't aware of different versions. Could you post that  as an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all Intel 7265 wifi cards have bluetooth, those that do will have a BDM(bluetooth MAC address) along with a WFM(wifi MAC) printed on the sticker that is on the card.

[image: Intel 7265 with bluetooth]

The picture shows an example of an Intel 7265 wifi with bluetooth